# Join two tables, display values from two table besides joint row

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have Table1 with rows A and B and Table2 with rows C and D.

I would like to join them on column B and C and also display corresponding values in column A and D.

Do not know where to start.

Regards,

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp start here

Comment: a good place to start will be MSDN documentation [`Sql Server INNER JOINS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select table1.a, table2.d
from table1
join table2 on table1.b = table2.c
```

Comment: I totally missed the fact that I can supply two tables in select statement. Sorry for lame question and thank you for the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
t1.A
,t1.B
,t2.C
,t2.D
FROM
table1 t1
Inner Join
table2 t2
On 
t2.C = t1.B
```